# Why can sin(Vector) on all cores be as fast as sin(V) on one core?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, openmp, trigonometry

I have a simple C++ code that runs a default sin function across a vector of values.

```
static void BM_sin() {
        int data_size = 100000000;
        double lower_bound = 0;
        double upper_bound = 1;
        random_device device;
        mt19937 engine(device());
        uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(lower_bound, upper_bound);
        auto generator = bind(distribution, engine);
        vector<double> data(data_size);
        generate(begin(data), end(data), generator);
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i = 0; i < data_size; ++i) {
                data[i] = sin(data[i]);
        }
        cout << accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0) << endl;
}
```

I get same time when I run this function with  `export OMP_NUM_THREADS` set to `1` and `8` having 8 cores. Also commenting line `#pragma omp parallel for` out does not help. So I wonder why sinus applied to a vector from all threads is as fast as applied from one thread?

(I compile with `-Ofast -fopenmp` on gcc-4.8)

Comment: Are you timing the whole function, or just the loop calling `sin`?  What fraction of the runtime is spent generating the random numbers?

Comment: @BenVoigt Having had the fun of noticing that the GNU Radio random source was pretty slow with mt19937, I can tell you that a normal cmath sine is faster than `uniform_real_dist<double>(mt19937)` by a factor of 10-200, depending on your machine.

Comment: write `Runtime * r =new Runtime();` before the loop and `delete r;` after it.
http://pastebin.com/x7yGYcdS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer is simple:

- Not all things scale well. I don't know `fast_sin`, but it's possible it's mainly memory-bandwidth limited. In that case, you'll win nothing by distributing the workload across cores.
- Also, I doubt your measuring methods. If your generator is the mt19337, it's a lot more complex than your sine, so parallelizing your sine doesn't do much, because most of the time is spent generating random numbers.

Comment: We (my old Westmere system and I) do not agree with the second bullet point. The MT19337 is way faster than the GLIBC sine implementation. Although it is the generator loop that is faulting the 763 MiB of vector memory for the first time, it is still twice as fast as the serial sine loop. On Sandy Bridge the generator loop is around 1,5x faster.

Comment: @HristoIliev interesting! Well, again, I don't really know `fast_sine`. If you used a taylor series approximation method with proper SIMD, you should be able to be much much faster than libc's `sinf`; see [VOLK's implementation of SIMD sines](https://github.com/gnuradio/volk/blob/master/kernels/volk/volk_32f_sin_32f.h), which at least exists for SSE4.1; I probably should write an SSE2 one, too. On my machine, it's 5 times as fast as libc sin, and has practically unmeasurable error compared to it.

Comment: Using Intel C++ with `-Ofast -xHost` results in 3,6x faster serial sine loop on both Westmere and Sandy Bridge. The loop runs 4,4x faster on Sandy Bridge and 4x faster on Westmere with 6 threads. But the OP is using GCC and its `sin` implementation, at least given the edited version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring something wrongly. The generator loop is slow, but not that slow that it completely overshadows the sine loop. Here are the results of measuring the execution speed of several code parts on two different Intel architectures:

```
 Code part             | WM (x64) | WM (x86) | SB (x64) | SB (x86)
-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------
 generate()            |  1,45 s  |  2,44 s  |  1,28 s  |  2,18 s
 sine loop (serial)    |  2,17 s  |  2,88 s  |  1,80 s  |  2,91 s
 sine loop (6 threads) |  0,37 s  |  0,51 s  |  0,31 s  |  0,52 s
 accumulate()          |  0,31 s  |  0,70 s  |  0,33 s  |  0,67 s
-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------
 speed-up: overall     |  1,85x   |  1,65x   |  1,78x   |  1,71x
 speed-up: sine loop   |  5,86x   |  5,65x   |  5,81x   |  5,60x
 speed-up: Amdahl      |  2,23x   |  1,92x   |  2,12x   |  2,02x
```

In the above table, WM stands for Intel X5675, a Westmere CPU, while SB stands for Intel E5-2650, a Sandy Bridge CPU. x64 stands for 64-bit mode and x86 - for 32-bit mode. GCC 4.8.5 was used with `-Ofast -fopenmp -mtune=native` (`-m32` for 32-bit mode). Both systems are running CentOS 7.2. The execution times are only approximate, as I haven't done proper timing by taking the average of multiple executions. Timing was done using the portable `omp_get_wtime()` timer routine.

As you can see, the overall speed-up with 6 threads ranges from 1,65x to 1,85x, while the speed-up for the sine loop alone ranges from 5,60x to 5,86x. Both the generator loop and the accumulator loop are performed in serial, which caps the parallel speed-up (see [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law)).

Two things to note here. First one, the generator loop could be a tad faster if the memory for the vector is pre-faulted. It basically means sweeping over the vector and touching every memory page that backs it. Running the generator loop twice and only timing the second invocation will also do the trick. On my systems that brings no noticeable advantage (the savings are on the same order as the measurement error), most likely since CentOS's kernel has transparent huge pages turned on by default.

The second thing is the last parameter to `accumulate()` is an integer 0, therefore the algorithm is forced to perform an integer conversion every time, which slows it down considerably and gives the wrong result at the end (0). `accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0)` executes ten times faster and also produces the correct result.